# Efficient solution for returning an object based on a key value in a very deeply nested collection?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have a collection with many objects in it. All the objects are deeply nested. I would like to return the objects based on a key value. But the key is at the very end of the nested object. Let me paste an example of the data:

```
[
{
  "_id": "5cac8858f0c65f0010451f6c",
  "dealsAllowed": [
    {
      "plan": "plan1",
      "newPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 10,
        "discountType": "points",
      },
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 40,
        "discountType": "points",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "plan12",
      "newPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 10,
        "discountType": "points",
      },
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 50,
        "discountType": "price",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "page45",
      "newPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 20,
        "discountType": "points",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "wall5",
      "newPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 30,
        "discountType": "price",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "mars4",
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 60,
        "discountType": "points",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "glob07",
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 60,
        "discountType": "points",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "advent11",
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 50,
        "discountType": "price",
      }
    },
    {
      "plan": "advent1",
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 70,
        "discountType": "price",
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
    "_id": "5ca73621a926e60010e7dbe4",
    "dealsAllowed": [
        {
            "plan": "rover10",
            "newPlanDeal": {
                "discount": 75,
                "discountType": "price",
            },
            "oldPlanDeal": {
                "discount": 75,
                "discountType": "price",
            }
        }
    ]
},
.....
]
```

Now to find the desired objects, I check the property "discountType" if its value is either "points" or "price". Any of them that I get. My solution is like following:

```js
let result = []
 _.forEach(allDealObjects, deal =>
     _.forEach(deal['dealsAllowed'], plan => {
         _.forEach(plan, type => {
             type.discountType === 'price' ? result.push(deal) : null
         })
      })
 )
```

Now my particular solution works fine. And it is easier to read as well. I am just wondering if there is a better solution or a compact one for my understanding as playing with deeply nested objects would come up again in the future and their has to be better ways than looping over them. am I right? Does there exist a better practice that I can adopt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [CodeReview.se]

Comment: @phuzi sorry i din't knew if such community existed. I'll revert to that. But I am curious why isn't this question suitable for this particular platform as I am actually not  asking for a review but a better approach.

Comment: @gameFrenzy07: there seems to be a fair bit of disagreement here around that.  I personally think this is fine here.

Comment: When asking a question on StackOverflow the hints on how to ask a good question states: "The community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems." This implies you have a problem that needs fixing. Whereas the hint on CodeReview states "Improve code that you wrote or maintain, through peer review." This seems to fit better the question you're asking.

Comment: @phuzi: The phrase you're quoting doesn't exist in the "How to Ask" page.  It doesn't even mention the word "community."

Comment: @RobertHarvey It's on the "Ask Question" page

Comment: @phuzi: I'm not going to go look for it.  This question is perfectly acceptable here.  Cherry-picking some phrase out of a "rule book" doesn't change that.

Comment: Fair enough, I wasn't cherry-picking though, that is what has made the difference to me about where a question belongs. As Scott Sauyet stated, there is disagreement ;)

Comment: @phuzi: I usually treat CodeReview as working more with details of implementations.  Questions like "this works, but seems wrong-headed; are there better options?" seem well-suited for SO, especially when the question show some actual effort as this one does.  It does lose some points in my mind for not showing the requested output or having a runnable snippet, but on balance, I find this a decent question, and well fit for SO.

Comment: @phuzi It does appear to be on-topic on CR but please use a normal close reason -  e.g. "Needs more focus" (like I did) instead of the fact that it is on-topic there as a reason. Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353), [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: Thank you very much @ScottSauyet and RobertHarvey and phuzi. Your discussion only proves how much the community cares about the sanctity of this platform. I would put even more effort next time to get everything right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.filter` and `.map` (instead of `_.forEach` and `.push` would be more idiomatic and also result in less nesting.

```js
let allDealObjects = [{
    "_id": "5cac8858f0c65f0010451f6c",
    "dealsAllowed": [{
        "plan": "plan1",
        "newPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 10,
          "discountType": "points",
        },
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 40,
          "discountType": "points",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "plan12",
        "newPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 10,
          "discountType": "points",
        },
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 50,
          "discountType": "price",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "page45",
        "newPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 20,
          "discountType": "points",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "wall5",
        "newPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 30,
          "discountType": "price",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "mars4",
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 60,
          "discountType": "points",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "glob07",
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 60,
          "discountType": "points",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "advent11",
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 50,
          "discountType": "price",
        }
      },
      {
        "plan": "advent1",
        "oldPlanDeal": {
          "discount": 70,
          "discountType": "price",
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ca73621a926e60010e7dbe4",
    "dealsAllowed": [{
      "plan": "rover10",
      "newPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 75,
        "discountType": "price",
      },
      "oldPlanDeal": {
        "discount": 75,
        "discountType": "price",
      }
    }]
  },
];

let result = allDealObjects
  .filter(deal => deal.dealsAllowed
    .flatMap(planObj => Object.values(planObj))
    .some(plan => plan.discountType === 'price'));

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanks @junvar for your answer. I do actually want to add the "deals" instead of "plans". So what i do in the end is, I use lodash's function _.uniq() which removes all duplicates. Can u please edit your answer for pushing deals instead?

Comment: @gameFrenzy07: It would help if you edited the question to show the expected output.

Comment: Updated to return deals instead. You need 2 levels of iterations to keep track of deals while processing within them.

Comment: @junvar thanks for the very helpful answer and edits. I just want to ask some stuff. So your solution really is compact and elegant. But doesn't my solution seems more readable? I guess what I am trying to ask is what is more preferable and in the future when i face the same problem, what should I choose. Would really appreciate your input.

Comment: Styles choices depend on personal preference and consistency with the code base. But in general, `[].forEach|filter|map|some|etc...` is preferred to traditional `for` loops in Javascript. They're remain readable as the code becomes more complex. One exception is when you need sequential async code.

Comment: @gameFrenzy07: I'd suggest that yours looks more readable to you because of familiarity.  If find this code much more readable, although I would quibble with the code layout.  `filter` / `(flat)map` / `some` are much more expressive than `forEach`.  Moreover, as I read the original, it seems to me that it will add multiple copies of the deal, once for each time you match the "price" `discountType`.  I assume that's not what's wanted.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes my original solution was indeed adding multiple copies of the deal. So I, in the end would just use Lodash library's _.uniq() method, which would take care of multiple copies. There were lot of problems with my approach. That's why I wanted to get a better opinion here. Glad I did that and learned some stuff.